# Visual Studio test run button is disabled

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

[image]

Does anybody know how to make it available?

Comment: Did you set up a Run/Debug Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of stupid mistake. The reason was the abstract modifyer in the test class description. So I guess the reason was that class couldn't be instanciated so test wouldn't start.